# Gulp. Включение одного и того же файла несколько раз

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

Доброго времени суток, сообщество StackOverflow.
Совсем недавно начал разбираться с gulp и столкнулся с проблемой: при добавлении в src одного и того же файла, он начинает игнорироваться после первой обработки.

Например,

```
gulp.src(['file1.html', 'file2.html', 'file1.html'])
    .pipe(concat('all.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/dir'));
```

К сожалению после запуска скрипта в all.html получается лишь такая структура:

- file1.html
- file2.html

И на этом все.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Не подскажете, как её решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вполне ожидаемое поведение. Вы, вероятно, хотите использовать один html-файл в качестве шаблона и вставлять его несколько раз в вашу верстку? Если так то используйте `gulp-rigger`

Установка:

```
npm install gulp-rigger --save-dev
```

в gulpfile.js

```
rigger = require('gulp-rigger'), //использование шаблонов

gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src(path.watch.html)
    .pipe(rigger())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html));
});
```

И теперь вы можете объединять html вот так. Например в all.html:

```
<div class="content">
 //= templates/file1.html
 //= templates/file2.html
 //= templates/file1.html
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Также, если по каким то причинам, вам не подходит `gulp-rigger` можно воспользоваться [`gulp-add-src`](https://github.com/urish/gulp-add-src).

В вашем случаи примерно так:

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
return gulp.src([
    'file1.html',
    'file2.html', 
])
.pipe(addsrc.append('file1.html')) 
.pipe(concat('all.html'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('/dir'));
});
```